# Is there a way to append a value to a prop? React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-animations

My current problem is that my animation is not activating for the correct `id` that was assigned:

```
    anim_star = (id) => {

  let progress = this.state.progress;
  progress[id] = new Animated.Value(0);

    this.setState({ progress });
console.log(this.state.progress);
  Animated.timing(this.state.progress, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 2000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
  }).start();

}
```

The `console` result of that is here:

[image]

Where you see the `10: AnimatedValue`, the `10` represents the `id` that I clicked on for that animation. For some reason, the animation is not playing for `10`.

Here is my attempt to try and (I guess) append the correct `id` to the `AnimatedValue`:

```
   <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={this.anim_like.bind(this, item.id)}>
          <Animation
          progress={this.state.progress[item.id]} // Here is where I think I need to fix.
          source={require('../Animations/favourite_app_icon.json')}

          />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Is there a way to mocked what I have going on in the `console.log`?

Comment: What is 'Animation' component. You can only animate `View`, `Text`, `Image`, and `ScrollView` for other components you have to use `Animated.createAnimatedComponent()`. Check the react-native docs. First check if the animation is working without providing any id's then make it work with id's, this way you can debug the error.

Comment: @RaviRaj from Lottie

Comment: @RaviRaj Also, Yes the animation works without id's, but without id's all animations play at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot grasp your code. But try this change, in your `Animated.timing` line where animation starts, change `this.state.progress` to `this.state.progress[id]`. It may work.

Comment: @RaviRaj I get console log result of nothing when I add in the [id].What can I do to help you understand my code?